# UV's and Normals

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, normals

Question 1. Is about normals. To my understanding there is a way to visualize them better red being faced inward and blue being faced outward or something to that nature. Sometimes the lighting in some areas makes it hard to tell which way the normals are facing i.e like a roof overhang for example.

Question 2. I need my wood planks to be horizontal on the entire structure but they're only facing horizontal on the clock tower part and not the maim structure. Would that be taken care of in UE4?, Unreal is only letting me adjust the length and width of the texture not the orientation. Or did i set up my UV's wrong on that part of the structure and that's why they're vertical instead of horizontal?.

Comment: 1. If you hit "N" then check in "Backface Culling" in the right-side menu, then the backfaces will be transparent as in the game engine. 2. Yes, your UVs orientations wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Faces coloured blue when normals are facing outwards and red when facing inwards is doable in Blender 2.80
You can enable that option in the **Overlays** dropdown menu : 
[image]

Personally I find it more useful to work with **Backface Culling** enabled. **Viewport Shading** dropdown :
[image]

The answer to the second question is to edit the relevant UV islands in Blender. Simply select them and rotate 90°.

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer question 2 as I have no knowledge of Unreal

For question 1 from what I understand you have Face Orientation turned on as per image 1.

[image]

You can also show the face normal by as seen in the image

[image]